# How to assign an ip address to a vm from the host with using python?

Tags: python, ip, virtualbox, assign

I'm using virtualbox and trying to assign an ip address to my virtual machine from the host. I need to do this with python. My host is Windows 10 and vm is ubuntu 16.4.

Note: if you'll say how to do it with vboxmanage, that will do, too. So i can create a python script with subprocess.

Comment: Could you use ssh to connect and perform the action?

Comment: I prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of example for this at https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

You should be able to take it from there

Comment: That didn't help.